# MQ Support pac MA01- Q Program

Tags: security, authorization, ibm-mq

I want to use the Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01) to move messages between two different queues. It works without any issue on a Windows box.

I am trying to run this on an AIX box and I receive the **2035 - Not Authorized** error message.

I specify the flag `-u <userid>` when i execute the copy command and yet it keeps stating

```
MQOPEN on Object 'queue name' returned 2035 Not authorized..
```

My command line looks like the one below:

```
q -u <myuserid> -xb -m sourceQMgr -I sourceQueue -m TargetQMgr -oDestinationQueue -p20
```

The user `<myuserid>` does have the relavent permissions to read and write from the queue.

Appreciate any pointers or assistance.

Comment: What platform(s) are the source and destination QMgrs on?  Presumably Windows as well?  What version of WMQ on the QMgrs?

Comment: Rob, both the QMgrs are running on the same AIX box. When the Q program runs it does say "User Id changed to :'<userid>' implying the usage of the -u flag is correct. I am guessing that it worked on the windows box as i am logged in as Windows administrator. This userid is not even part of mqm group in the windows machine so i am a bit stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Q program, the `-U` parameter sets the user ID in the message *but not the ID used to connect to the QMgr*.  If you look at the connection handle on the queue while you are connected on the Windows box you will see that the ID associated with the handle is your login ID and not `myuserid`. However, the message's `MQMD.UserID` *will* contain `myuserid` after a `PUT`.

When you use administrative privileges, this authorization is automatically granted.  In this case you mentioned that on the Windows box you are logged on as the administrator which would allow that option.  If on the AIX box you are not using an ID in the mqm group then the `+setid` authority would need to be explicitly granted in order to use the `-U` option.

For example, assume that `myuserid` belongs to `mygroup`.  To make the `-U` option work you would need to do this:

```
# +setid must be granted at both the QMgr *and* the queue
setmqaut -m TargetQMgr -t qmgr -g mygroup +connect +inq +setid
setmqaut -m TargetQMgr -n DestinationQueue -t queue -g mygroup +put +inq +setid
```

Note that `+setid` only applies to putting messages and not getting them.  However, because the Q program may specify the `setID` option on the connect to the first QMgr it's possible the errors you see are generated there.  If that is the case, run the same commands on the source QMgr:

```
# +setid must be granted at both the QMgr *and* the queue
setmqaut -m SourceQMgr -t qmgr -g mygroup +connect +inq +setid
setmqaut -m SourceQMgr -n SourceQueue -t queue -g mygroup +browse +get +inq +setid
```

For reference, please see the help for the Q program which states:

```
-U        Sets the user ID in the message.
```

...and the Infocenter section on *[Granting authority to set context](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc/sy13660_.htm)*.

Incidentally, I couldn't find a `-u` (lowercase) option so I'm assuming it's just a typo in your post and you are actually using `-U`. That option produces the desired message when I tried it on my workstation.

Comment: Rob,both -u (lowercase) and -U (uppercase) seem to work. In either case, the application states  User Id changed to '<userid> so I am guessing both are valid options.

Comment: D'oh! I didn't even think to try it. Learned something new again today.  Thanks!